# How to do, Do while loop for this code?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have this java code:

```
public class Ages {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

    int value = 0;
    String name;
    int age;



        System.out.print("Hey, what's your name? ");
        name = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Ok, " + name + ", how old are you? ");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

           do{
            if(age < 16){
            System.out.println("You can't visit in the museum, " + name + ".");

            if(age < 18);
                 System.out.println("You can't visit in the park, " + name + ".");
            }
            if (age < 25){
                System.out.println("You can't visit if you have a car, " + name + ".");
            }
            if (age >= 25){
                System.out.println("You can do anything, " + 
                    name + ".");

            }
            while(age > 300);
            System.out.println("It's not correct..Try Again, " + name + 
             ".");


            }
}
```

and I need that user write the wrong answer, he will get the question again "how old are you?", and after he get another tries..
what I goona do? 
Thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: Put the part where you take the input inside the `do {} while()` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One** the while block is not correct you have to use :

```
System.out.println("It's not correct..Try Again, " + name + ".");

do {
    if (age < 16) {
        System.out.println("You can't visit in the museum, " + name + ".");

        if (age < 18);
        System.out.println("You can't visit in the park, " + name + ".");
    }
    if (age < 25) {
        System.out.println("You can't visit if you have a car, " + name + ".");
    }
    if (age >= 25) {
        System.out.println("You can do anything, "
                + name + ".");

    }
    //while(age > 300);<<----------wrong position 

    System.out.println("It's not correct..Try Again, " + name + ".");

} while (age > 300);//<<----------correct position
```

**Two**

The while condition seams not correct, you have to check with min and max age, instead of just max, so you can use :

```
 while (age < minAge || age > maxAge );
```

So if the age is less then the min OR great then the max repeat again

**Three** this if will not ever executed :

```
if (age < 18);//<<----------------note the ; it mean your if is end
    System.out.println("You can't visit in the park, " + name + ".");
```

**Four**

Instead you can read the age inside your loop :

```
System.out.print("Hey, what's your name? ");
name = keyboard.next();
System.out.println();

do {

    System.out.print("Ok, " + name + ", how old are you? ");
    age = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    ....
}while(..);
```

---

Hope this can gives you an idea about your problem.

Comment: ':D it just happen @davidxxx haha you answer also is clear :)

Answer (score 3):

1)You should use this condition  :  `if (age >= 25 && age <= 300){` instead of 
            `if (age >= 25){`.

Otherwise the condition is `true` even if `age` is over 300 and you don't want to:

```
while(age > 300);
```

2)You should also allow the user to enter a new input if the value is not correct.

`age = keyboard.nextInt();` should be in the loop.

3) You should allow the loop to finish.

In the while statement, you could specify the condition that requires a new input from the user :

```
while (age > 300)
```

This gives the code (not tested) :

```
  int age;
  do{
    age = keyboard.nextInt();

    if(age < 16){
        System.out.println("You can't visit in the museum, " + name + ".");
    }
    else if(age < 18){
         System.out.println("You can't visit in the park, " + name + ".");
    }
    else if (age < 25){
        System.out.println("You can't visit if you have a car, " + name + ".");
    }

    if (age >= 25 && age <= 300){
        System.out.println("You can do anything, " + 
            name + ".");                
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("It's not correct..Try Again, " + name +  ".");
    }
  }                 
  while (age > 300);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need,  if the user write age not true he get another try to write his age again and after the answer.. why I don't get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, please:

```
public class Ages {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int value = 0;
        int age;

        System.out.print("Hey, what's your name? ");
        String name = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println();

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Ok, " + name + ", how old are you? ");
            age = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            if (age <= 300) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("It's not correct..Try Again, " + name +
            ".");
        }

        if(age < 16) {
            System.out.println("You can't visit in the museum, " + name + ".");
        }
        if(age < 18){
            System.out.println("You can't visit in the park, " + name + ".");
        }
        if (age < 25){
            System.out.println("You can't visit if you have a car, " + name + ".");
        }
        if (age >= 25){
            System.out.println("You can do anything, " +
                name + ".");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thans your answer but the output is: " Hey, what's your name? BOBO

Ok, BOBO, how old are you? 300

You can do anything, BOBO." and if the user writing dont correct answer he should get another try again : "how old are you?".. what I should do?

Comment: This is what you get as an output of executing my suggested code: `Hey, what's your name? Andrew

Ok, Andrew, how old are you? 302

It's not correct..Try Again, Andrew.
Ok, Andrew, how old are you? 301

It's not correct..Try Again, Andrew.
Ok, Andrew, how old are you? 300

You can do anything, Andrew.` Isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes!, this is what I looking for.. I try a lot to do this but I did not make it
 :(, do you know what I shuld do??

Comment: Just run the code I posted above in my answer. Because this is the exact output from running my suggested code.

Comment: ohh sorry, now I see what I wrong!, thanks alot!, now it work for me :), have a nice day!

Comment: You are welcome! So, if you like my answer you may upvote it or even choose as the right one, I do not mind :) Have a nice day too!